# imfindcircles not finding obvious circle

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I've tried the examples on the imfindcircles documentation which use much more complicated images and they worked fine.  But in the following code which generates a perfect centered circle and attempts to find it with imfindcircles I get an empty result.  I've been playing around with the parameters for imfindcircles, including ObjectPolarity, Sensitivity, and a radii range, but I've yet to get anything other than an empty result.

```
function annulusConvolve()
    function outputImg = generateCircle2(circleRadius)
        padding = 200;
        [xmesh, ymesh] = meshgrid(-circleRadius-padding:circleRadius+padding, -circleRadius-padding:circleRadius+padding);
    
        outputImg = zeros(size(xmesh));
    
        outputImg((xmesh.^2 + ymesh.^2) < circleRadius^2) = 1;
    
   
    end

    testPicture = generateCircle2(200);
    figure;
    imshow(testPicture);
    centers = imfindcircles(testPicture,200)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

worked ok for me if you try your example with:

```
centers = imfindcircles(testPicture,[195 205],'Sensitivity',0.99)
```

Comment: This works for me, but why does the sensitivity have to be so high?

Comment: its kind of a threshold. see more https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/detect-and-measure-circular-objects-in-an-image.html?s_tid=answers_rc2-2_p5_MLT